# Can the parent window be notified when a child window closes? (on a diff domain)

Tags: javascript, events, browser

Can the parent window be notified when a child window closes? (on a different domain?)

Trying to get around the window.opener not working when on different domains.

Can I at least be notified somehow when the child window closes?

Answer (score 14):

You can't directly be notified of the window closing, but you can work out when the child window has been closed by inspecting the [`closed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.closed) property on the window object reference returned by [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open).

Here's an example that will display an alert within 5 seconds of the child window being closed by polling the `closed` property:

```
var win = open('http://www.google.com');
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (win.closed) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            alert('Window closed! Hoorah!');
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: You cant be directly notified because the child window is in a separate domain, correct?

Comment: It's because there is no suitable browser event that you can use to work out when a window is closed.

Comment: A suggestion: If let's us say you create a popup window with a page you control (same domain) and from the popup triggers a redirect to an external domain, the `closed` property wont' be availble anymore. You may want to check the `parent` property of the popup window

Comment: @dickwan: nope, `closed` will still be available as cross-origin access is allowed to that window property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Window

Answer (score -2):

A better solution with two pieces of code
1/ in the popup :

```
$(window).bind('unload',
  function(){
    window.opener.PopupUnload(window)
  })
```

2/ in the parent (main window) :

```
function PopupUnload(wnd){
 setTimeout(function(){ // setTimeout is for IE
   if(wnd.closed)
     alert('You just killed me...')
  },10)
}
```

with this code, no function called forever (with setInterval()) and you make the difference between close and refresh popup (post/get)

(tested in IE8 and FF3)

Comment: Your `window.opener.PopupUnload` call is going to fail if the parent and popup windows are loaded from different domains due to cross site scripting restrictions.