# Detecting when a Cross-Domain Popup Window Closes

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript application that lives on say domainA.com. In order to authenticate a user and set cookies, it opens a popup window on domainB.com. (this is similar to Twitter's @anywhere).

**How do detect when the popup on domainB.com closes and call a function in the JavaScript that opened it on domainA.com?**

I've tried various methods like `window.opener`, `window.unload`, etc, but run into cross domain limitations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the parent window be notified when a child window closes? (on a diff domain)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781770/can-the-parent-window-be-notified-when-a-child-window-closes-on-a-diff-domain)

Answer (score 0):

window.postMessage will help you on browsers that support it...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage