# Cross-domain window.close event from parent window

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cross-domain

For example I'm on domain1:

```
a.click(function(){
  window.win=window.open(domain2,'name');
});
```

Now I'm on domain2 and I'm closing it. How will `window.win`  know that user closed that window? Is there any event or property to check via interval?

Comment: [Detecting when a Cross-Domain Popup Window Closes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851438/detecting-when-a-cross-domain-popup-window-closes) is very similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a property which is not part of any W3C spec. It's called `closed` and would get accessed like

```
if( window.win.closed ) {
    // window was closed
}
```

I'm not sure about the cross-browser compatibilty for that property. I'm also not sure how this behaves on cross-origin domains. But if you try it please let me and the rest of this community know about it.

---

Another option is that you take care for the notification yourself. That means, you are listening for the `onbeforeunload` within the popup-window. When the event fires, you could use HTML5's `postMessage` method to communicate between cross-domain windows. For instance:

MainWindow:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if( e.origin === 'http://www.popupdomain.com' ) {
        if( e.data === 'closed' ) {
            alert('popup window was closed');
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Domain2:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.opener.postMessage('closed', 'http://www.popupdomain.com');
};
```

The only caveat on this solution is that it's only compatible with browser that support basic HTML5. There are other (sneaky) ways to have a cross-domain communication on old'ish browsers, but I guess that is another story.

Comment: DOM object which is returned from window.open is empty. I wish there could be that closed property. Any other solution?

Comment: Guess i'll have to listen to this another story. :)

Comment: @Beck: that is because it doesn't work or you can't rely on html5 ?

Comment: I can't, i'm developing for IE7 as well.

Comment: This is a gem! Works perfectly on Chrome 31. And yes, @Somebody, if you `console.log()` the window returned from `window.open()` after it is closed, you get an empty instance of window. Try `console.log(window.win.closed)`, though. It returned `false` for me. I'd be very interested to see where else it works (particularly IE).

Comment: MDN indicates that `closed` property is part of HTML5 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed)

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the cross domain was closed by using an interval check on the windows closed property.

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var closeCheckInterval = 500; //Check every 500 ms.

var popup =  window.open(url, "_new", 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height);
popup.focus();

var closeCheck = setInterval(function () {
    try {
        (popup == null || popup.closed) && (clearInterval(closeCheck), onWindowClosed());    
    } catch (ex) { }
}, closeCheckInterval);

var onWindowClosed = function () {
    ...
    // Stuff to do after window has closed
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the similar problem in which a window of domain1 is opened from domain2. I needed to keep a check on when the window gets closed. I tried following :-

1. I used window.onunload event , it didn't work because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and showed following error

   Error: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
   Source File: chrome://firebug/content/net/httpLib.js

   Error: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
   Source File: chrome://firebug/content/firefox/tabWatcher.js
2. But I maintained an array of Window objects and applied **"Window.closed"** property , **it works even in cross domain.** :)
3. Also you can try [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)