# Losing reference to child window

Tags: javascript, window.open, extjs5

I am writing an Ext JS 5 application and seem to be losing a reference to a child window that I am opening.

The following opens a new window to w3schools, as a sample.  Later, when I close the window, the beforeunload event DOES NOT fire.

```
 this.chatPopOutWindow = window
                .open(
                    'http://www.w3schools.com',
                    'chatPopOutWindow',
                    'width=380,height=400,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,copyhistory=no,resizable=no');
            Ext.get(me.chatPopOutWindow).on('beforeunload', function() {
              .....more code
```

In this code sample with a bad url (the new window opens to a 404 error), when I close the window the beforeunload event DOES fire:

```
this.chatPopOutWindow = window
                .open(
                    '/someBadURL',
                    'chatPopOutWindow',
                    'width=380,height=400,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,copyhistory=no,resizable=no');
            Ext.get(me.chatPopOutWindow).on('beforeunload', function() {
              .....more code
```

Why does the beforeunload event not get triggered in the first scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure. I searched for a reference but didn't find. So, I believe this happens because the first scenario you're opening a window with a domain different from yours. In the second-one, even it being a badUrl, it's a relative url, which means, same domain as the opener.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736564/javascript-cross-domain-window-close-event-from-parent-window

Comment: Thanks, Evan, but it does not work even in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

I should have specified that the window I want to open is not cross-domain; it is in the same domain (though not in the example above).

Anyway, I found the answer.  Apparently, Ext JS 5's `Ext.get(me.chatPopOutWindow).on('beforeunload', function() {...` is not reliable.  Instead, use `me.chatPopOutWindow.onbeforeunload = function() {...`, which is the JavaScript syntax for listening for a beforeunload event..