# How Can a parent window know that its child window closed?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

I want to execute a function when an opened child window is closed. Child window opening code is:

```
outWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=600, height=400, top=100, left=100);
```

I want to call a Javascript function written in parent window. I am using YUI-2 for developing the plugin.
How can I make it work? What event should be registered?

Comment: Also refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712195/js-listen-when-child-window-is-closed

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
var intervalID, childWindow;

childWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com");

function checkWindow() {
    if (childWindow && childWindow.closed) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        alert('closed');
    }
}
var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkWindow, 500);
```

References: [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781770/can-the-parent-window-be-notified-when-a-child-window-closes-on-a-diff-domain).

Simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aUYU/).

Comment: I can't figure out why OPiazao's answer is marked as the correct answer here.  THIS is the correct way to handle it based on the requirements described in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

You can try acces the parent window by:

```
window.opener.functionThatYouWant();
```

This code is inside de child window.

But if you open an window that the URL is in another domain (not localhost), you can't access it because of security issues.

I used this code on Firefox, I am not sure if it works crossbrowser.

Comment: It works fine in Safari, but it didn't seem to work in chrome.

Comment: Yeah, seems to have this problem. But the Mark's answer below seems better and it is crossbrowser, try it as well.