# How to listen for child window closing?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cross-domain

I am opening a child window for Facebook sharing this way:

```
window.open(sharingUrl,'','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
```

The window is automatically closed when a user clicks share or close...

Is there a way to add a listener to these events?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If you store a reference to the child window when you call `window.open()`, then you can poll using `setInterval()` to see whether the window is still open using the `window.closed` property. The example below checks twice per second.

```
var child = window.open('http://google.com','','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);

function checkChild() {
    if (child.closed) {
        alert("Child window closed");   
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

**Note to others:** If you are ever in a situation where you have control over the html in the child window, you could make use of the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event and alert the parent window.

Comment: Then you could create a dynamic page which generates an iframe of 100% size, and that page will fire the `onbeforeunload` upon closing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was under the (false) impression that the variable where I stored the created window would be null or undefined after closing the window, so this is a handy new bit of info for me.

Comment: Works like a charm! :)

Comment: Why does this work if the `setInterval` is calling a function not defined until afterwards?

Comment: @HelpingHand Due to function hoisting.

Comment: Won't this not work in places like Chrome under default conditions which will block the popup and the reference to child will be null? Therefore you would call .closed on a null/undefined which I think might error out. Oh, and Chrome will block the popup if the page just tries to open it without user interaction.

Comment: @PeterP. You are correct. This answer doesn't guard against that case. I wrote some simple code here to show a general solution to the stated problem. There is definitely more things to consider.

Comment: @jessegavin its amazing !! thank you very much. my problem solved.

Comment: @jessegavin, What if the window.open(url) is already set and you don't create it? How would you close a window(s) that are predefined on a page and perform a task such as a reload of the page when that window is closed?

Comment: In 2022 I faced an issue: if the url in child popup is changed it anyway fired as child.closed.

Answer (score 24):

For future references, I'd like to share another solution that doesn't require `setInterval` :

```
var child = window.open('http://google.com','','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
child.onunload = function(){ console.log('Child window closed'); };
```

Comment: A constructive comment instead of a minus 1 would be appreciated. What browser did you use to test this.

Comment: Same-Origin applies, which makes attaching handlers like this impossible for different domains.

Comment: I tried this. But the unload event is getting fired even if user navigates to different webpage from same child window. How to detect actual window closure?

Comment: @diosney You may have already solved the problem, but leave a comment for those who are currently searching for similar problems. I created with the window opening function disabled so that the unload event could only be identified when the window was closed.

Comment: onunload occurs when the user navigates away from the page

Answer (score 2):

var child = window.open('http://google.com','','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

```
// Called even when loading and unloading.
child.onunload = function(){ 

    // What matters here
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (child.closed) {
            console.log('Child window closed'); 
        }
    }, 300);
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer saved after hours of fighting

Answer (score -2):

This will work fine

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>Detecting browser close in IE</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onbeforeunload = function(){ myUnloadEvent(); }
function myUnloadEvent() {
    alert ('You can have Ur Logic Here ,');

}

</script>
</head>
</script>
</head>
<body >
<h1>Close the Window now</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work for Oleg because he is opening a Facebook page in the child window. He doesn't (I am guessing) have the ability to change html's Facebook code.

Comment: He doesn't, it would be a security issue, you're very limited regarding cross domain operations.