# How can I detect when a child window is CLOSED (not simply refreshed)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload, postmessage

I'm aware of the `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` events. Unless I'm mistaken, those are *not* what I need because they both fire whenever the current *page* is unloaded—which means they fire for page refreshes and when the user navigates away (to another URL) as well.

My scenario is this. I have created a child window using `window.open` for the purpose of displaying other websites, for review purposes (the users of the application are reviewing websites according to various criteria). The child window is navigating around quite a bit, thus the `onunload` event is fired frequently.

I'd like to know when the browser window itself is actually *closed*, so that the parent window can report something like:

> "You've closed the preview window; would you like to reopen it?"

Is this possible?

Comment: Just check the new url and the [`childWindow.closed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.closed) property at every `unload` event?

Comment: @Bergi: Oh, there's a `closed` property? Perfect!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712195/js-listen-when-child-window-is-closed

Comment: The Edge browser seems to fire the `onunload` event before setting `closed` to true.

Comment: onunload is getting fired even if user navigates to different page from the same child window. This example works well. It detects actual popup closure  -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/5712425/3337028