# javascript or jquery to capture the newtab opened by current tab( via click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

javascript or jquery to capture the new tab opened by current tab( via click)

```
var win = window.open(url,properties..)
```

like the above

script to capture the newtab (not new window)that is created by

```
document.getElementById('#submit').click();
```

is it possible like following !!?

```
var win = document.getElementById('#submit').click();

win.close();
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to prevent a user from opening a new window from clicking an `a` link or `form` submit?

Comment: No, i want to listen to that newtab for closing event and excute a function in the maintab after the newtab closed .

Comment: Gotcha, this looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712195/js-listen-when-child-window-is-closed

Comment: ya that's work but there window.open() is used, the url is need to use that. I am sure no Url, the click event is must.when i am click on a submit btn, a newtab is open i want that newtab to be listened

Comment: Unless a new tab/window is opened by your javascript, you aren't going to be able to listen for another tab window from your original page.

Comment: is that anyway via window.name, window.title....