# setinterval working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am using set interval function. Below is my code

```
popupWindow = window.open ('test.php','_blank','width='+w+',height='+h+',toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable =no,directories = no');
            x = popupWindow.outerWidth ;
            y = popupWindow.outerHeight ;
            var timer = setInterval(function() {  
    if(popupWindow.closed) {  
       clearInterval(timer);  
        alert('closed');  
    }  
}, 1000);
```

This is working chrome and IE but not firefox. Please help

Comment: Kindly share the console log error with us.

Comment: Check out a previous answer I gave http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712195/js-listen-when-child-window-is-closed/5712425#5712425

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: when i tried to alert something inside setinterval nothing happened and the js file didn't run after this

Comment: @jessegavin : but what is wrong with this ??

Comment: Do you see any errors in the javascript console in Firefox?  https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/38974b6b-4cf1-42c8-8491-c714d63ca347/0b888c30e5ae93fe/res/3ba3ac17-2f35-4c20-bd1b-af0aa86cbf8b/skitch.png

Comment: no error when i tested in firebug

Comment: @jessegavin ur approach in that post also didn't work

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Firefox  http://codepen.io/jessegavin/pen/epZLxP

Do you have popups disabled?

Comment: @jessegavin upon closing the window was alert message displayed ???

Comment: yes that is what happened for me in the codepen link. See screencast http://screencast.com/t/KBgtGynj1