# Does ANYone know how to get the Javascript ‘onunload’ function to work?

Tags: javascript

I’ve looked at all the other Javascript ‘onunload’ questions  & I think I’ve understood them but I still don’t seem to be able to get this function to work.

Specifically I’m developing an app to run under Apple’s Safari browser and I’m trying to catch the window closing event triggered by clicking on the red Window Close gumdrop on the extreme upper left of a Safari browser window.

If I click on the red Close Window gumdrop the window closes but the ‘onunload’ function isn’t accessed and executed.

BUT … If I reload the page, the ‘onunload’ function IS accessed and executed.

That’s fine but what I’m really trying to do is have some code executed AFTER  the red Window Close gumdrop is clicked on.

My code simply doesn’t work.

I’ve either misunderstood something or I’m missing something.

Does any body have an idea what I’m missing or doing wrong ?

Here’s the test source I’ve written to see if I can get the Javascript ‘onunload’ function to work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Window - 'onunload' Javascript function Test</title>
        <script>
          function WindowOnUnLoadTest ()
          { alert ("Entering … 'WindowOnUnLoadTest' …");}
          window.onunload=WindowOnUnLoadTest;
        </script>
     </head>
     <body onunload="WindowOnUnLoadTest()">
     </body>
</html>
```

20151024
Here's the edited code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html> 
     <head>      
        <title>Window Open Test 3</title>
         <style>

            #Image_01_Closed
            {
                position    : absolute;
                left        : 16px;
                top         : 16px;
            }
        </style>
         <script>
            var URL_Set_Prefix                  = "file:///Users/simonwhelan/Desktop/WindowOpenTest3/";
            var File_PathName                   = "";
            var Window_01A_Closed_File_PathName =  URL_Set_Prefix + "Window-01A-Closed";
            var Window_01A_Open_File_PathName   =  URL_Set_Prefix + "Window-01A-Open"  ;
            var Window_01B_File_PathName        =  URL_Set_Prefix + "Window-01B-Open"  ;
            var Window_01B_HTML_File_PathName   =  URL_Set_Prefix + "Window-01B.html"  ;
            var Window_Open = false;
            var Window_01B  = null;

            function turnAnImageOnOrOff (imageArrayIndexNbr,
                                         id,
                                         src)
            {
                if (Window_Open === true)
                     { File_PathName = Window_01A_Closed_File_PathName; }
                else { File_PathName = Window_01A_Open_File_PathName  ; }

                document.getElementById(id).src = File_PathName;        
                open_Or_Close_A_Window (imageArrayIndexNbr); 
                Window_Open = !Window_Open; 
            }

            var current_Window_B_X_Position_Value = 8;
            var current_Window_B_Y_Position_Value = 8;

            function open_Or_Close_A_Window (imageArrayIndexNbr)
            {
                if (Window_Open === false)
                     {
                        Window_01B = window.open (Window_01B_HTML_File_PathName, 
                                                  "_blank", 
                                                    "top  = " + current_Window_B_X_Position_Value + ", " 
                                                  + "left = " + current_Window_B_Y_Position_Value); 
                     }
                else {  Window_01B.close(); };      

                File_PathName = URL_Set_Prefix
                               + Window_01B_HTML_File_PathName;                 
            } 
        </script>
    </head>

     <body>
        <img 
            id           = "Image_01_Closed" 
            src          = "Window-01A-Closed"
            alt          = "Window A-01 - Closed" 
            onclick      = "turnAnImageOnOrOff (0, id, src)"
            width        = "80" 
            height       = "80"
        >
    </body>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
      <head> 
        <title>Window B-01 Open</title>
          <style>
            #Page_Background
            {
                position    : absolute;
                left        : 8px;
                top         : 8px;
            }
         </style>

          <script>
            function WindowOnUnLoadTest ()
            {
                console.log("Entered WindowOnUnLoadTest");
                return "Done with WindowOnUnLoadTest";
            }
            window.onbeforeunload=WindowOnUnLoadTest;
        //    window.onunload=WindowOnUnLoadTest;
         </script>

     </head>

      <body>
        <img 
            id      = "Page_Background" 
            src     = "Window-01B-Open"
            alt     = "Window B-01 Open : Page Background" 
            width   = "80" 
            height  = "80"
        >
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: For some reason StackOverflow clipped off the 1st 3 and the last lines of the source.

Comment: you need to precede each line of code with four spaces, or select the code and click the `{}` button - fixed it for you

Comment: The Javascript functions `onunload()` and `onbeforeunload()` have quite a few restrictions applied to them. Visitors don't like websites abusing those functions to prevent visitors from leaving by alerting stuff, poping something up etc etc. So most browsers prevent the use of those functions for anything that stops the user from closing the website when they want to :)

Comment: So instead of alerting, try opening your browsers console (detach it or you lose the console on close) and edit your code by removing the alert and adding `console.log ( 'unload triggered' );` Now the console should show you if it works or not.

Comment: On a side note: Keep in mind dat `onunload()` and `onbeforeunload()` aren't relyable functions! If the browser closes unexpectedly (crash, internet down, process kill), these functions will never trigger.

Comment: @CupawnTae :

Thanks for properly indenting my source. I thought I HAD properly indented it … but … apparently not.

Comment: I get your point that there are restrictions on BOTH ‘onunload’ & ‘onbeforeunload’.

I tried using  “console.log (‘unload triggered’)” but it doesn’t work either.

Or … more correctly … occasionally  the ‘onunload’ Alert will appear when I reload the page.

The reason why I’m truing to do this is that the page I’m closing was actually opened by a button on ANOTHER page … and … If I use the close button on the page that has been opened then the button state on the page that opened this page will get out of synch with the button state on that page.

Here’s the revised source …

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
  <head>
  <title>Window - 'onunload' Javascript function Test</title>
    <script>
function WindowOnUnLoadTest ()
{
    alert   ("1. We got to here …"); 
    console.log  ("2. We got to here …");
    alert   ("3. We got to here …"; 
}

   console.log ("4. We got to here …");

window.onunload=WindowOnUnLoadTest;

    </script>
 </head>
  <body onunload="WindowOnUnLoadTest()">
  </body>
</html>

Comment: By the way … I’m using Safari 9.0 running under Mac OS 10.9.5 .

If you have any suggestions I’d be very grateful if you could pass them my way.

And … Thank you very much for all your time and your help.

Comment: @SimonWhelan you can always edit your own post, so if you want to update/add source, it's better to do that (and you can fix any formatting issues while you're at it :-)

Comment: @SimonWhelan how are you communicating "button state" between your pages (and what is that state)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing the alert is that the browser won't allow you to pop up alerts in those event handlers. But you can still do some things.

If you really want a dialog for debug purposes, you can do it by returning a string from you `onbeforeunload` function - you'll get a confirmation dialog displaying the text. E.g., try this:

```
<script>
    function WindowOnUnLoadTest ()
    {
        console.log("Entered WindowOnUnLoadTest");
        return "Done with WindowOnUnLoadTest";
    }
    window.onbeforeunload=WindowOnUnLoadTest;
</script>
```

(note that you should actually use `window.addEventListener()` instead of assigning to `window.onbeforeunload`)

In fact, you're pretty much there with your existing code - you can simply call a function in the parent window from your `onbeforeunload` handler, as long as they're in the same domain.

Try adding another function to your parent script:

```
function onChildClose() {
  // here you can update your main page's state, change the image etc.
  alert("[debug] child closed");
}
```

And then in your child page's `WindowOnUnLoadTest` function, do this:

```
window.opener.onChildClose();
```

If your pages are in different domains, you can poll to check when the window closes, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5712425/1469259).

Comment: Hi CupawnTae :

Thanks for your replies.

I apologize for not getting back to you earlier … I’ve been preoccupied with other things.

In the future I’ll append the modified source to the original posing.

Comment: Hi CupawnTae :

I’m not sure that I’ve communicated clearly why I’m putting the ‘alert’ & ‘console.log’ statements in the ‘onunload’ & ‘onpreunload’ functions.

The only reason why I’m putting these function calls inside ‘onunload’ & ‘onpreunload’ is simply to verify that the functions are being called.

I’m using a ‘button’ in a Source Browser window to open up a Target browser window.

If I click on the ‘button’ in the source window a 2nd time it closes the Target window and toggles the button to it’s ‘closed’ state. That works fine.

Comment: The problem arises when I click on the ‘Red Gumdrop” close button on the target window.

I say “‘Red Gumdrop” close button” because I am developing under Safari 9.0 on Mac OS 10.9.5 .

The Target window closes OK, but, of course, the ‘button’ on the Source window remains in its ‘Open’ state when it should actually flip to its ‘Closed’ state in order to remain in synch with the Target window.

Comment: If ‘onunload’ can pick up a ‘mouse closing’ event or whatever function is actually called when the Red Gum Drop is clicked on then I could use ‘window.opener’ function to close the ‘button’ associated with the Target window on the Source window to make sure the Target window and the associated button on the Source window are in synch.

In fact, I’m not actually using buttons on the Source window. Instead I’m simply using a pair of images that I simply toggle between when the ‘mouseclick’ function spots a mouse click happening on 1 of the 2 images.

Comment: I hope the foregoing clarifies what I’m actually trying to do.

I’ve appended the revised source to the original posting so you can see my actual code.

Thanks for all your help and if you have any idea or suggestions as to how I can pick up in the Javascript source for the Target window NOT the source window I’d really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi CupawnTae :

I tried your code.

‘onbeforeunload=WindowOnUnLoadTest’

will put up the alert dialog when it executes but it doesn’t seem to log the console.log string to the console (return "Done with WindowOnUnLoadTest";).

Substituting ‘onunload’ for ‘onbeforeunload’ doesn’t work at all in that it neither puts up an alert dialog nor logs the text to the console.

This means that I can use the ‘window.opener’ function to close the associated button in the source window.

Comment: This is not ideal in that I would rather not have an alert dialog come up asking the user if they want to close the target window. I just want the Target window to close when the user clicks on the Red Gumdrop button on the extreme upper left of the browser window.

Is there any way to get ‘onunload’ to do that ?

If not then do you have any idea how to get ‘addEventListerner()’ to do that.

Thank you for all your help and suggestions & once again I apologize for taking so long to get back to you.

Comment: @SimonWhelan the confirmation dialog was really only meant to demonstrate that the code is actually running... I've updated the answer to include communicating back to your parent page - I think this should achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to get back to you … I’ve been preoccupied with other things.

But  … I really have to thank you for all your help … I was able to use your last set of suggestions to solve the problem.

And … As a bonus … It also works with ‘onunload’ as well as ‘onbeforeunload’.

I’ve posted the ‘Answer” source on the “Answer” section of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to the question I posed.

I had a LOT of help from 'CupawnTae' in getting this answer.

Here's the revised source. I've tested it and it does seem to work.

// The Source Window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html> 
   <head>
        <title>Window Open 4</title>
       <style>

            #Image_01_Closed
            {
                position    : absolute;
                left        : 16px;
                top         : 16px;
            }
      </style>
       <script>
var URL_Set_Prefix                  = "file:///Users/simonwhelan/Desktop/WindowOpenTest4/";
var Window_01A_Closed_File_PathName =  URL_Set_Prefix + "Window-01A-Closed";
var Window_01A_Open_File_PathName   =  URL_Set_Prefix + "Window-01A-Open";
var Window_01B_HTML_File_PathName   =  URL_Set_Prefix + "Window-01B.html";
var the_Current_id = "";
var Window_01B   = null;
var current_Window_B_X_Position_Value = 8;
var current_Window_B_Y_Position_Value = 8;

function handleAMouseClickOnAnImage (id,
                                     src)
{
    the_Current_id  = id;

    if ((Window_01B == null) || (Window_01B.closed == true))
         { 
            document.getElementById(id).src = Window_01A_Open_File_PathName;
            Window_01B = window.open (Window_01B_HTML_File_PathName, 
                                      "_blank", 
                                        "top  = " + current_Window_B_X_Position_Value 
                                      + ", " 
                                      + "left = " + current_Window_B_Y_Position_Value); 
         }
    else {  Window_01B.close(); };

    the_Current_id  = id;
}

function onChildClose ()
{
    document.getElementById(the_Current_id).src = Window_01A_Closed_File_PathName;
} 
      </script>   
  </head> 
   <body>

        <img 
            id           = "Image_01_Closed" 
            src          = "Window-01A-Closed"
            alt          = "Window A-01 - Closed" 
            onclick      = "handleAMouseClickOnAnImage (id, src)"
            width        = "80" 
            height       = "80"
        >
  </body>     
</html>
```

// The Target Window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
      <head> 
        <title>Window B-01 Open</title>
          <style>
            #Page_Background
            {
                position    : absolute;
                left        : 8px;
                top         : 8px;
            }
         </style>
          <script>
    function WindowOnUnLoadTest ()
    {
        window.opener.onChildClose();

        console.log("Entered WindowOnUnLoadTest");
        return "Done with WindowOnUnLoadTest";
    }
//    window.onbeforeunload=WindowOnUnLoadTest;
    window.onunload=WindowOnUnLoadTest;
         </script>

     </head>
      <body>
        <img 
            id      = "Page_Background" 
            src     = "Window-01B-Open"
            alt     = "Window B-01 Open : Page Background" 
            width   = "80" 
            height  = "80"
        >
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @CupawnTae … Thanks for the advice … I will try to be mindful of it in the future …