# How can I detect the closing of an external window in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a piece of code that opens a window with:

```
  $("#authorization_link").click(function() {
    win = window.open($(this).attr("href"),'width=800,height=600');
  });
```

Now I want to run another block when window `"win"` is closed. What is the event and how do I run code on its detection?

Comment: you can add there `onbeforeunload` handler that will call to `opener` window

Comment: Palash thanks for the pointer, but the spawned window in this case is to another website to which I have no control.

Comment: you can run with `setInterval` and check if `win` is `!=` null

Comment: This is a good question, I don't think you can get this much access to a window you don't control for XSS/CSRF reasons, but I would be curious to see what people have to say.

Comment: One moment i will give you the code for it

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5240471/1823841

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use intervals to check when/if the window was close Here is how you'll do it:

```
win = window.open($(this).attr("href"),'width=800,height=600');

function checkIfWinClosed(intervalID){
    if(win.closed){
        alert('windowsClosed');
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    checkIfWinClosed(interval);
},1000);
```

And here is a working example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gp7NP/3/)

Hope that helps.