# link on page calls a servlet after execution go back to previous page

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I have a HTML page. On the page I have a link. When the user click on the link, I am calling a servlet which opens in a new page. On this servlet, I'm trying to update my database. After completing the update, I'm able to close the page launched from the servlet. Now I want to run a script on the original HTML page, but am unable to do so, since there is no trigger/event to call that method.

How do I do this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, your servlet doesn't "open a new page", it performs an operation and ends by displaying a page or redirecting to another page. Please clarify.

Comment: when the user hits the link, he is directed to a new URL(which opens in a new browser window and is out of my control) which is a call to the servlet eg: demo.html is my current html page. When user hits the link a new new window will open with url: <servlet-url-mapping>?<some-parameters>

Comment: try to redirect user using url provided by `request.getHeader("Referer")`

Answer (score 1):

You could use ajax to poll the status of your backend process executed by the servlet. When it is finished, you execute whatever you want. Something like:

```
var checkStatusTimeout;

function checkStatus(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./getstatus",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(status){
            if (status == 'FINISHED'){
                clearTimeout(checkStatusTimeout);
                // execute whatever you want here
            }
        }
    });

    checkStatusTimeout = window.setTimeout("checkStatus()", 5000);
}
```

You should call the function checkStatus() when the user clicks on the link.

Or you could assign the child window used by the servlet to a variable and check it from time to time to verify if the window was closed. Check the answer from Mark Coleman on [javascript: How Can a parent window know that its child window closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240428/javascript-how-can-a-parent-window-know-that-its-child-window-closed) for instructions.

Comment: Let me add some more details to my question. The link is actually in a tooltip from a view I have embedded from tableau online. Whenever I click the link,a call to "tableau server" is made, which then redirects me to a new page(I can control the link to this page) which opens in a new tab. I'm calling the servlet from this link. In the servlet I'm able to modify my database. Now I want to go back to the previous page and then update the view. I can update the view using JS but for that I need to run a script on the original page.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, when clicking on the link a new tab is opened and when the servlet finishes this tab is closed. Is that right? If so, you could use the answer from Mark Coleman and run a script on the page 1 to check when page 2 (the servlet tab) is closed. When that happens, you can update the view. Will that do the trick or did I miss something?